# How to fix structure related errors in c?

Tags: c

I have written this code in c-:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct chemical_elements {
    char element_name[100];
    char element_symbol[10];
    int atomic_number;
    int atomic_mass;
};

void main() {
    int i;
    chemical_elements elements[118];
    char elements_name[120][20]={" ","Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminum","Silicon","Phosphorus","Sulfur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Cesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","Gadolinium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Nihonium","Flerovium","Moscovium","Livermorium","Tennessine","Oganesson", " "};
    for (i=1;i<=118;i++) {
        elements[i].atomic_number=i;
        elements[i].element_name=elements_name[i];
    }       
    getch();
}
```

I was making it for telling element electronic configuration but when I checked in between writing the code, on compiling it, I found it was giving these errors-:

```
new5.c(13): error C2065: 'chemical_elements': undeclared identifier
new5.c(13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'elements'
new5.c(13): error C2065: 'elements': undeclared identifier
new5.c(13): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
new5.c(16): error C2065: 'elements': undeclared identifier
new5.c(16): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
new5.c(17): error C2065: 'elements': undeclared identifier
new5.c(17): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Is there any idea on how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Start with `chemical_elements elements[118];` -> `struct chemical_elements elements[118];`

Comment: ...then there will me one more error left here: `elements[i].element_name=elements_name[i]`. You cannot assign strings in C. You need `strcpy(elements[i].element_name,lements_name[i]`. It's explaind in details in the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: In C++, it is sufficient to write `chemical_elements elements[118];`. However, in C, `struct` identifier names are in a different namespace, so that you must always use the keyword `struct` when declaring them, unless you are using a `typedef`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I didn't knew that we don't need struct with typedef in C since I am new to it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok and thank you. I am replying again since old comment got deleted, if you have read it then please ignore it.

Comment: Off by 1.  `{"Hydrogen" ....` --> `{"neutron", "Hydrogen" ...` to make `elements[i].element_name=elements_name[i];` correct offset, use `strcmpy()` to copy name.

Comment: While not advisable, it's still possible to reference to a string without copying it to a new memory region; as long as it's just about reading data off `elements[i]`, one may just use a pointer instead of allocating a new array in `elements[i]`, since the data segment is shared regardless of scope (within a process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying in the name and atomic number, initialize the array with those values.

```
struct chemical_elements {
    const char *element_name;
    const char *element_symbol;
    int atomic_number;
    double atomic_mass;
};

const struct chemical_elements elements[] = {
  { "Hydrogen", "H",  1, 1.0079 }, 
  { "Helium",   "He", 2, 4.0026 },
  ...
  { "Oganesson", "Og", 118, 294 },
}

const size_t chemical_elements_n = sizeof chemical_elements / chemical_elements[0];
```

---

I see little reason for the `.atomic_number` member.  Consider below and use the array index as the atomic number.

```
struct chemical_elements_alt {
    const char *element_name;
    const char *element_symbol;
    double atomic_mass;
};

const struct chemical_elements_alt elements[] = {
  { "Neutron", "Nu",  1.00867 }, 
  { "Hydrogen", "H", 1.0079 }, 
  { "Helium",   "He", 4.0026 },
  ...
  { "Oganesson", "Og",  294 },
}
```